# React. Fromik. Material-ui form submit event testing fails using react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, formik, react-testing-library

I have a react app using Formik and Material-ui.
I grabbed the submit button html element,
But fireEvent is not working.
I think the issue is coming from Formik library layer.
'Button' component is a reusable material ui button.
'change fireEvent' tests are passed.

But I receive 'Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.' message for 'submit fireEvent'.

### loginForm.test.js

```
import { Router, MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { queryByAttribute } from 'react-testing-library';
import React, { render, cleanup, fireEvent } from '../../../setupTests';
import LoginForm from '../../../../components/auth/login/loginForm';

afterEach(cleanup);

const mockSubmit = jest.fn();
const mockKeepMeLoggedIn = jest.fn();

const defaultProps = {
  handleSubmit: mockSubmit,
  isSubmitting: false,
  userData: [],
  keepMeLoggedIn: mockKeepMeLoggedIn,
};

const setUp = (props = {}) => {
  const setupProps = { ...defaultProps, ...props };
  const component = render(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <LoginForm {...setupProps} />
    </MemoryRouter>,
  );
  const { container, getByTestId, getByText } = component;
  const getByName = queryByAttribute.bind(null, 'name');
  const usernameInput = getByName(container, 'username');
  const passwordInput = getByName(container, 'password');
  const getByType = queryByAttribute.bind(null, 'type');
  const submitButton = getByType(container, 'submit');


  return { component, usernameInput, passwordInput, submitButton };
};

describe('Login Form Component', () => {
  it('simulate input type and click the form submit button', () => {
    const { usernameInput, passwordInput, submitButton } = setUp();
    fireEvent.change(usernameInput, { target: { value: 'yuch' } });
    expect(usernameInput.value).toBe('yuch');
    fireEvent.change(passwordInput, { target: { value: 'testpwd1234' } });
    expect(passwordInput.value).toBe('testpwd1234');

    fireEvent.click(submitButton);
    expect(mockSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

### loginForm.js

```
 ...

        import { Formik, Form } from 'formik';
        /* --- Components --- */
        import FormikField from '../../../shared/form/formikField';
        import PasswordField from '../../../shared/form/passwordField';
        import Button from '../../../shared/form/formButton';

        const LoginForm = ({
          keepMeLoggedIn,
          keepLoggedIn,
          userData,
          handleSubmit,
          loginValidation,
        }) => {
          const foundUsername = userData.length !== 0 ? userData[0].username : '';
          const values = { username: foundUsername, password: '' };
          return (
            <Formik
              initialValues={values}
              validationSchema={loginValidation}
              onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            >
              {({ isSubmitting }) => (
                <div className="login-container">
                  <Form
                    className="flex flex-column-m center"
                    data-testid="form"
                  >

            <FormikField
              label="아이디"
              name="username"
              type="text"
              icon="filledUser"
              styleName="textField"
              required
            />
           ...
            <Button
              typeValue="submit"
              variantValue="contained"
              buttonName="로그인"
              className="login-btn"
              isSubmitting={isSubmitting}
            />
          </Form>
         ...
        </div>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};
```

### button.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = theme => ({
  ...
});

const FormButton = ({
  typeValue,
  variantValue,
  buttonName,
  width,
  isSubmitting,
  classes,
  className,
}) => {
  ...
  return (
    <Button
      type={typeValue}
      variant={variantValue}
      color="primary"
      size="small"
      style={widthStyle}
      className={`${className} ${classes.button}`}
      disabled={isSubmitting}
    >
      {buttonName}
    </Button>
  );
};
```

### Things I have tried.

[ To get submit button ]

1. ```
   const getByType = queryByAttribute.bind(null, 'type');

   const submitButton = getByType(container, 'submit');

   -> console.log(submitButton) // HTMLButtonElement

   -> fireEvent.click(submitButton)
   ```
  2.

```
const submitButton = getByText('로그인');

-> console.log(submitButton) // HTMLSpanElement

-> fireEvent.click(submitButton)
```

3. ```
   const submitButton = getByTestId('form');

   -> console.log(submitButton) // HTMLFormElement

   -> fireEvent.submit(submitButton)
   ```

[ form ]
1. html 'form' instead of 'Form' from Formik.

```
import { Formik, Form } from 'formik';

<Formik
      initialValues={values}
      validationSchema={loginValidation}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    >
      {({ handleSubmit, isSubmitting }) => (
        <div className="login-container">
          <form
            className="flex flex-column-m center"
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            data-testid="form"
          >
          ...
          </form>
```

Comment: Have you tried firing a submit event to the Form element?

Comment: Yes I have as I wrote above in 'What I have tried' section.

Comment: I grabbed the Form element form using 'getByTestId'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually has to do with how Formik handles the submit. Since it is using a promise, it takes at least a tick before the onSubmit call is being called.

Testing library has a [wait](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#wait) utility which waits for a given time. But since we only need to wait for a single tick, we can just omit the duration.

First, import wait from react-testing-library. Then make your `it` function `async` and wrap the expect part with a `wait` function.

I've tested this with a click event on the submit button.

```js
// import wait
import { wait } from 'react-testing-library';

// add async
it('simulate input type and click the form submit button', async () => {
  const { usernameInput, passwordInput, submitButton } = setUp();

  fireEvent.change(usernameInput, { target: { value: 'yuch' } });
  expect(usernameInput.value).toBe('yuch');

  fireEvent.change(passwordInput, { target: { value: 'testpwd1234' } });
  expect(passwordInput.value).toBe('testpwd1234');

  fireEvent.click(submitButton);

  // wrap expect in `await wait`
  await wait(() => {
    expect(mockSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```